# Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (D): `c' used

Tags: longtable, arrays

```
\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{Probit Models\label{tab5}}
\begin{tabular}{l*{6}{D{.}{.}{-1}}}
\toprule
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(6)}\\
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{earlyprob}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{earlyprob}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{earlyprob}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{earlyprob}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{earlyprob}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{earlyprob}\\
\midrule
earlyprob           &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     \\
h\_per1011=1         &           0         &                     &           0         &           0         &                     &           0         \\
                    &         (.)         &                     &         (.)         &         (.)         &                     &         (.)         \\
\addlinespace
h\_per1011=2         &       0.179\sym{**} &                     &       0.197\sym{**} &      0.0434         &                     &       0.118         \\
                    &      (2.98)         &                     &      (3.16)         &      (0.38)         &                     &      (1.01)         \\
\addlinespace
h\_per1011=3         &       0.474\sym{***}&                     &       0.550\sym{***}&       0.401\sym{***}&                     &       0.497\sym{***}\\
                    &      (9.59)         &                     &     (10.07)         &      (3.94)         &                     &      (4.56)         \\
\addlinespace
r\_10disability=1    &                     &           0         &           0         &                     &           0         &           0         \\
                    &                     &         (.)         &         (.)         &                     &         (.)         &         (.)         \\
\addlinespace
r\_10disability=2    &                     &      -0.157\sym{*}  &      -0.275\sym{***}&                     &      -0.229         &      -0.322\sym{*}  \\
                    &                     &     (-2.29)         &     (-3.91)         &                     &     (-1.74)         &     (-2.39)         \\
\addlinespace
r\_10disability=3    &                     &      -0.232\sym{**} &      -0.484\sym{***}&                     &      -0.227         &      -0.432\sym{**} \\
                    &                     &     (-3.26)         &     (-6.37)         &                     &     (-1.61)         &     (-2.86)         \\
\addlinespace
s\_10disability=1    &                     &                     &                     &           0         &           0         &           0         \\
                    &                     &                     &                     &         (.)         &         (.)         &         (.)         \\
\addlinespace
s\_10disability=2    &                     &                     &                     &      -0.419\sym{***}&      -0.419\sym{***}&      -0.418\sym{***}\\
                    &                     &                     &                     &     (-3.43)         &     (-3.47)         &     (-3.41)         \\
\addlinespace
s\_10disability=3    &                     &                     &                     &      -0.528\sym{***}&      -0.508\sym{***}&      -0.511\sym{***}\\
                    &                     &                     &                     &     (-4.11)         &     (-3.97)         &     (-3.94)         \\
\addlinespace
r11bmi:w11 body mass index=kg/m2&                     &                     &                     &      0.0257\sym{***}&      0.0309\sym{***}&      0.0294\sym{***}\\
                    &                     &                     &                     &      (3.68)         &      (4.35)         &      (4.09)         \\
\addlinespace
BMI\_det1011         &                     &                     &                     &       2.787\sym{*}  &       2.862\sym{*}  &       2.882\sym{*}  \\
                    &                     &                     &                     &      (2.09)         &      (2.14)         &      (2.15)         \\
\addlinespace
bmi\_detint          &                     &                     &                     &     -0.0734\sym{*}  &     -0.0751\sym{*}  &     -0.0759\sym{*}  \\
                    &                     &                     &                     &     (-2.15)         &     (-2.20)         &     (-2.22)         \\
\addlinespace
ear\_x10             &                     &                     &                     &   -0.000358         &   -0.000714         &   -0.000429         \\
                    &                     &                     &                     &     (-0.26)         &     (-0.54)         &     (-0.31)         \\
\addlinespace
r10ssdi:w10 r is receiving ssdi&                     &                     &                     &       1.792\sym{***}&       1.881\sym{***}&       1.817\sym{***}\\
                    &                     &                     &                     &     (12.69)         &     (13.35)         &     (12.74)         \\
\addlinespace
rassrecv: r receives socsec&                     &                     &                     &      -1.948\sym{***}&      -1.893\sym{***}&      -1.908\sym{***}\\
                    &                     &                     &                     &     (-9.73)         &     (-9.47)         &     (-9.52)         \\
\addlinespace
1.white/caucasian   &                     &                     &                     &           0         &           0         &           0         \\
                    &                     &                     &                     &         (.)         &         (.)         &         (.)         \\
\addlinespace
2.black/african american&                     &                     &                     &       0.635\sym{***}&       0.671\sym{***}&       0.638\sym{***}\\
                    &                     &                     &                     &      (5.75)         &      (6.13)         &      (5.74)         \\
\addlinespace
3.other             &                     &                     &                     &       0.262         &       0.299\sym{*}  &       0.235         \\
                    &                     &                     &                     &      (1.84)         &      (2.12)         &      (1.64)         \\
\addlinespace
ragender: r gender  &                     &                     &                     &       0.128         &       0.111         &       0.127         \\
                    &                     &                     &                     &      (1.51)         &      (1.32)         &      (1.49)         \\
\addlinespace
married             &                     &                     &                     &      -0.313\sym{*}  &      -0.331\sym{*}  &      -0.310\sym{*}  \\
                    &                     &                     &                     &     (-2.23)         &     (-2.37)         &     (-2.19)         \\
\addlinespace
wealthy             &                     &                     &                     &      -0.198\sym{*}  &      -0.247\sym{*}  &      -0.203\sym{*}  \\
                    &                     &                     &                     &     (-1.98)         &     (-2.49)         &     (-2.03)         \\
\addlinespace
r10higov:w10 r is covered by gov plan&                     &                     &                     &      -2.049\sym{***}&      -1.999\sym{***}&      -2.042\sym{***}\\
                    &                     &                     &                     &    (-18.95)         &    (-18.73)         &    (-18.79)         \\
\addlinespace
r10\_PublicEarn      &                     &                     &                     &    -0.00322         &    -0.00389         &    -0.00326         \\
                    &                     &                     &                     &     (-1.09)         &     (-1.30)         &     (-1.09)         \\
\addlinespace
r10covr:w10 r covered by r empl plan&                     &                     &                     &      -0.298\sym{**} &      -0.335\sym{**} &      -0.290\sym{**} \\
                    &                     &                     &                     &     (-2.72)         &     (-3.08)         &     (-2.64)         \\
\addlinespace
Constant            &       0.328\sym{***}&       0.726\sym{***}&       0.629\sym{***}&       2.658\sym{***}&       2.835\sym{***}&       2.770\sym{***}\\
                    &     (10.23)         &     (11.95)         &     (10.11)         &      (7.51)         &      (7.90)         &      (7.62)         \\
\midrule
Observations        &        3667         &        3498         &        3498         &        1944         &        1943         &        1943         \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\footnotesize \textit{t} statistics in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\)}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You need `\usepackage{dcolumn}`

Answer (score 5):

The `D` column type is defined by the `dcolumn` package. So add

```
\usepackage{dcolumn}
```

to your document.